# Laravel 5.1: can't upload a video file

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-form

On submitting a file I had this following error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'video_ogg' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `profiles` (`about_me`, `video_ogg`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (lorem, , 2017-07-23 02:15:50, 2017-07-23 02:15:50))
```

which states that the field `video_ogg cannot be null` but when I verify on debugging mode this field is not empty (see below)

controller

```
    public function store(Request $request)
   {
      // Validation //
      $validation = Validator::make($request->all(), [
         'about_me' => 'required',
         'video_ogg'    => 'required|mimes:mp4,ogx,oga,ogv,ogg,webm|min:1|max:3240',
      ]);

      // Check if it fails //
      if( $validation->fails() ){
         return redirect()->back()->withInput()
                          ->with('errors', $validation->errors() );
      }

      $profile = new Profile;

      //Debugging
      dd($request->files);

      // save media data into database //
      $profile->about_me = $request->input('about_me');
      $profile->video_ogg = $request->input('video_ogg');
      $profile->save();

      return redirect('/profile')->with('message','You just created your profile!');
   }
```

debugging result

```
FileBag {#45 ▼
  #parameters: array:1 [▼
    "video_ogg" => UploadedFile {#30 ▼
      -test: false
      -originalName: "mov_bbb.ogg"
      -mimeType: "audio/ogg"
      -size: 614492
      -error: 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Here as you can see on debugging the video is uploaded or I mean is in the request array but I still have an error message.

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'video_ogg' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `profiles` (`about_me`, `video_ogg`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (lorem, , 2017-07-23 02:15:50, 2017-07-23 02:15:50))
```

view

```
{!! Form::open(['url'=>'/profile', 'method'=>'POST', 'files'=>'true']) !!}
...
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="video_ogg">Upload Video (ogg)</label>
         <input type="file" class="form-control" name="video_ogg">
      </div>
...
```

which output this

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8000/profile" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="KxvK6tONoUhBCx58ESlbE1hh9eP8hy5nQyNqb62W">
```

So I did verify that `enctype="multipart/form-data"` is in the form.

model

```
class Profile extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = ['video_ogg', 'about_me'];
}
```

Comment: Have you set `video_ogg` to be fillable on your model?

Comment: Can  you try `dd($request->input('video_ogg'))` and post the result?

Comment: @VandolphReyes it's null

Comment: How about.
`$v_ogg = $request->input('video_ogg')

dd(v_ogg->mimeType)
`

Comment: @VandolphReyes Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: I don't understand why the `Filebag` (see above: debugging mode) contains the video file uploaded but `$request->input('video_ogg')` doesn't contains nothing

Comment: @AaronFahey yes;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you should use `file` method instead of `input`:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#files